# Why when I go back to previous page, I have an incorrect url (Chrome under iOS, browser back)

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, backbone.js

Single page application using Backbone.

I navigate to page 1 where the url is `baseurl/public#items#254`, after that I go to page 2 where the url is `baseurl/public#itemname`. I hit browser back button and I'm back to page 1 but the url is changed to `baseurl/public#items%23254`. I don't understand why the page 1 url is not the same when I navigate back and forth to it.

I can reproduce this only to Chrome browser under iOS platform.
Anyone had this problem and found a solution?

Comment: Take a look at the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850781/multiple-hash-signs-in-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to separate by /. Example: baseurl/public#items/254 - router 'items(/:id)'